# Magento 2 Integration Test for Custom Entity Attribute

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes, integration-test

I'm developing a Magento 2 module and within it's integration tests I'd like to write a quick test to check if a certain entity (in my case *category* from *catalog* module) has a custom attribute by it's name / code.

I have already created the test-case-class, my question is about how to formulate the test.

Comment: There is a nice channel maintained by [Vinai](http://magento.stackexchange.com/users/766/vinai) called [`Mage2Katas`](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCRFDWo7jTlrpEsJxzc7WyPw/videos) which covers everything related to TDD development in Magento2, you can see the videos to get an idea regarding the approach for testing you module and setting up the test environment for integrity testing